# Please help me about static object

Tags: java, oop

I wrote a piece of Object-Oriented code about Static object,please help me about this code! thank you very much!
When class B object is created,a7 get assigned first or the constructor 'public B(int i)' executed first？
I know this code is complicated,so thanks everyone a lot!

```
class A {
    int value;
    static A a1 = new A(1);
    public A(int i) {
        System.out.println("initialize A"+i);
        value = i;
    }

    public A(A a) {
        System.out.println("copy from A"+a.value);
        value = a.value;
    }
    static A a2 = new A(2);

}

class B {
    A a8;
    // A a7 = new A(a6);
    A a6 = new A(6);
    static A a3 = new A(3);
    static A a4;
    static {
        a4 = new A(4);
    }
    static A a5 = new A(5);

    public B(int i) {
        System.out.println("initialize B"+i);
        a8 = new A(8);
    }
    A a7 = new A(a6);
}

public class Initialization {
    static B b1 = new B(1);
    static B b2;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main begins");
        A a9 = new A(9);
        b2 = new B(2);
        System.out.println("main ends");
    }
}
```

Comment: The [JLS Chapter 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) might answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initializers for the instance variables (`a6` and `a7`) are executed and the variables are assigned **before** the body of the constructor is executed.  (But after the constructor's explicit or implicit "super" call.)

It doesn't matter whether the instance variable is declared before or after the constructor.

This is all specified in [JLS 12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).  The JLS is the best place to look for answers to *deep* questions about the semantics of the Java language.

---

I don't understand why you asked about "static objects" here:

- Objects are not `static`.
- Variables can be `static`.
- Methods can be `static`.
- Inner classes can be declared as `static` ... but this has a rather different meaning.

An object whose reference is assigned to a `static` variable; e.g.

```
    static B b1 = new B(1);
```

has the same semantics as if the reference was assigned to an instance variable or a local variable; e.g.

```
    private B b1 = new B(1);
```

The `static` doesn't alter what happens when you `new` the object.

Comment: Thank you. Your help inspired me a lot